# How to track how long an item in Android listview stays on screen

Tags: java, android, android-listview, analytics, android-event

Is there a way to detect the entry and exit of a particular item in the list and find the time difference between two events?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the items in the list view are being reused.
In the method "getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)" of the BaseAdapter the parameter "convertView" is you list item view. You can save the timestamp of its last update, second time you can get it and find out the difference.